# Does Sagemaker multi-model support Batch Transform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Sagemaker [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/multi-model-endpoints.html) explains that we can create an endpoint that can support multiple models. However, I can't find the documentation on how the same model can be used for Batch Transform. 
Can the same model that is used in multi-model endpoint be also used for Batch Transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can the same model that is used in multi-model endpoint be also used for Batch Transform?

Not currently.

However, you can use an inference pipeline Model to back an Endpoint or to run a Batch Transform job: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/inference-pipelines.html